# Differentiating Backend vs. Frontend Purchases in Magento

Tags: magento, reporting

Is there a way to tell if an order was placed through the frontend of the web site or entered through the administrative panel?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

By default, Magento only stores the `remote_ip` in table `sales_flat_order` for an order that is place by customer (while admin order is set to null).

So try this:

```
if(!empty($order->getRemoteIp()){
  //place online
}
else{
  // place by admin
}
```

See [Programmatically differentiate between admin & customer-placed orders](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/16757/programmatically-differentiate-between-admin-customer-placed-orders)

Comment: Thanks for nice hook +1 from me @R.S

Comment: I am trying to imagine that if magento was installed on a cloud host, the order either placed by customer or admin will have a remote IP Address. I stand corrected

Answer (score 8):

Every order has a `store_id`, when entered through administraction it will either be 0 (for 'admin' store) or null.

```
if ($order->getStoreId()) {
    // was placed via frontend
}
```

Don't use `getStore()` as that won't always return the admin store object reliably.

**Does not work with latest versions of Magento. (see comment)**

Comment: clockworkgeek's answer is correct. I'll add one other way, that is mostly helpful to administrative users that aren't programmers.  If you are looking at the order in the administration screen (Admin -> sales -> Orders) it will have a "Placed from IP" field if the order was created from the frontend, but if it was done through the admin backend screens it will not be there.

Comment: @sdek - That's a nice tip, I wasn't aware of it before.

Comment: Does not work with latest versions of Magento. You have to choose store id before create order within admin backend. So store_id will always have a value different from 0.

Comment: Yaroslav Rogoza is right! It will return the store id for which the order is placed, even from admin panel

Comment: So can someone answer this question?

Answer (score 0):

You can check the `is_super_mode` value (I have only check on the quote : `$quote->getIsSuperMode()`)

Comment: Where did you find this field? I can't find it for Magento 1.7