# Magento - Determine if order was placed through admin

Tags: magento, location

I was wondering if there was anyway of determining whether an order was placed via the website or through the admin backend (by an admin user)?

And also (optionally) the logged in admin users name that placed the order?

Something like:

```
$orderId = 100000010;
$order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->loadByIncrementId($orderId);
$location = $order->getWhereTheOrderWasPlaced();
$userThatDidTheOrder = $order->getUserThatDidTheOrder();
```

I've done a get_class_methods() call on the order $object but nothing jumps out at me.

Thanks!

Comment: I've had a look, but I can't find anything either.  Could the IP address of the order be used maybe?  It might not be set when an admin placed an order.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Differentiating Backend vs. Frontend Purchases in Magento](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4570909/differentiating-backend-vs-frontend-purchases-in-magento). (Nick is right to suspect the IP address)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I asked this question a while back.. here's the answer I got: [Differentiating Backend vs. Frontend Purchases in Magento](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4570909/differentiating-backend-vs-frontend-purchases-in-magento)

Answer (score 2):

By default magenta only store the `remote_ip` in table sales_flat_order for order that is place by customer (and admin order is null).

So try

```
if(!empty($order->getRemoteIp()){
  //place online
}
else{
  // place by admin 
}
```

See [Programmatically differentiate between admin & customer-placed orders](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/16757/programmatically-differentiate-between-admin-customer-placed-orders)