# Magento 2 - Check if order created from admin panel

Tags: php, magento2, magento2.1

Is it possible in Magento 2 to check: is order created from admin panel?

In M1 it was a problem with a strange [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4570909/differentiating-backend-vs-frontend-purchases-in-magento).
I checked `store_id` in M2 after creating order from admin panel and it's not empty. I searched for other fields that define this information, but haven't found

UPD: also looking for solution that differs from checking `remote_ip` field